# Update Syntax Error in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Just a quick question, because I'm stuck and currently probably blind.. where is the syntax error? (mysql and sqlite say #1064)

```
UPDATE `table` (`field2`) VALUES ('1') WHERE `field1` = 'asd';
```

Comment: it should be `UPDATE \`table\` SET field2 = 1 WHERE field1 = 'asd'`. please see this [**documentation on UPDATE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its

```
UPDATE `table`
SET field2 = 1 
WHERE field1 = 'asd'
```

You're getting your INSERT and UPDATE queries confused :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason why the VALUES syntax isnt supported in the UPDATE command?

Comment: `VALUES` generally takes a comma seperated list of values, which (I believe) is only used in `INSERT` statements. `UPDATE` statements on the other hand `SET` fields

Answer (score 2):

You have missed `SET` Keyword in the query.

`Update Table_name` **SET**`comlun = value where column2 = value`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```